# usbnet driver and network subsystem

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking

I am working on a project "AVB" bridging. We are doing audio-video streaming over the ethernet. The packets streaming takes place through the USB. Its like USB-ETH(MAC) chip, with USB connected to the host side. We are using "usbnet.c" driver. And we have two applications(User space processes) :

1) A daemon providing synchronization.

2) A talker program sending audio packets(1722).

There is function pointer implemented in usbnet called .ndo_start_xmit. And we have registered our function using this function pointer so that our implemented function gets called whenever there is a packet to be transmitted from the upper layer. When we run the daemon alone, the system is working pretty much fine.
But as soon as we start with the talker program in parallel, for some packets from the daemon, xmit function doesnt get called.
The freq. of packets sending from talker program is much high compared to the packets sent by the daemon.
So its like the talker program which is also sending packet through the same interface is affecting the behavior of daemon due to this effect. But still in dilemma whether how to resolve this issue...

Let me clear more.

Now suppose I have two applications transmitting packets through the same interface for e.g eth6. According to the perceived knowledge we know that when there is a packet to be transmitted .ndo_start_xmit is called. But one of application has a requirement that the packet should be exactly be transmitted out of MAC within 125 msec.
When I run 1st application let us name it "A", the packets leave MAC at every calculated 125 msec. THis timing is controlled by application itself. But when I start executing application "B", the "A" application packets doesnt get transmitted out of packet every 125 msec. Because of application B sending packets at 8,000/sec.And "A" sending @ 8/sec.

I think that the software queue in the subsystem that queues all the packets coming from the socket piles up all the "A" application packets along with many "B" application packets and then calls ndo_start_xmit in a row for all the piled up "A" app packets for transmission.
And thus we are not able to transmit packets at every 125 msec out of MAC.

Comment: Unless the tx queue below your apps can be prioritised, I can't see any obvious answer with the info. you have provided.  Can that lower-level tx queue count be inspected so that it's contents can be kept down, or its size reduced so that latency is less of a problem?

Comment: ..or is there another notification you can get when a packet has been handled and successfully transmitted, some sort of completion event?

Comment: There is a function called netif_queue_stopped():that tests if transmit queue is flowblocked , I am planning to implement this to know the status of the queue linked with ndo_start_xmit. Will update the results soon :)   - Sumeet

Comment: Now as that queue falls into n/w subsystem category, I think there are minimum chances we can play with it.

Comment: I looked at some usbnet.c code on net. 'dev->net->stats.tx_packets++;'  Maybe you can do something with that to limit the number of queued packets.  It would be nice if it called a user-supplied function at that time too, so you could signal a semaphore if the number of outstanding packets dropped to some low-water-mark, but no:(

Comment: IIRC (from 1996) `start_xmit` is only called when the card is idle and a packet is enqueued; the driver is supposed to send out subsequent packets automatically, until the queue becomes empty. So no, this function is not called once per packet.

Comment: dev->net->stats.tx_packets++ is just for maintaining the status of the packets whether dropped or transmitted successfully.

Comment: When I was running my code, netif_stop_queue gets called many times that disables the queue from queueing any other packets into the queue. But still the app continues sending packets from the user-space and when we sniff packets through wireshark, not a single packet gets missed. That means all the packets are transmitted. And also means that above this queue, there is mechanism implemented to preserve packets from the user-space when the queue is full and then queue it back when space is available in the queue. Is my supposition correct ??  - Sumeet

Comment: I am printing the seq_id of the packets received from the user-space in the driver( place: tx_fixup function in .ndo_start_xmit). When I am running the daemon alone(Transfer rate of daemon is 8 packets/sec). It gets printed fine i.e once for every packet. But as soon as I start another daemon (Transfer rate 8000 packets/sec), the seq_id of 1st daemon gets printed twice. But I dont know the exact reason. May be because the endpoin buffers are full and the kernel subsystem retries to send the packet. For every packet transmitted from 1st daemon, seq_id gets printed twice. -Sumeet

Comment: My project involves USB subsystem. Actually we are emulating another project involving PCI subsystem(Also the NIC(Which is ethernet over PCI) is different compared to our NIC (i.e it is ethernet over USB chip)

Comment: Now in the applciation "A" which invloves PCI subsystem, I am printing the time difference between two "send" API getting called for consecutive 2 packets. It shows 125usec because the hardware is leaving packet at every 125usec and hence as a result "send" gets called after every 125 usec.But in our project involving USB subsystem, the same application calls "send" API at every 20-40 usec which is against our protocol rules but to our surprise the difference between the two packets received at other side of the machine is 125 usec.

Comment: I am using wireshark on the other side of the machine which is receiving the app "A" packets.
My query is why the "send" is getting called so frequently ? -Sumeet

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the [Linux Hardware Multiqueue](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/networking/multiqueue.txt) API.

Comment: Hey friend, Can you elaborate more on this issue ? . Which kind of queue( Hardware ) is being discussed here and how I can implement it. It will be a great help. -Sumeet